# Single page application versioning

Tags: javascript, caching, version, versioning, single-page-application

What is the best way to make suer the user is using the latest version of my **Single Page Application**? How can I make sure that the user won't have to hit **ctrl+F5** to get the latest page resources **(JS+CSS)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix all references to static files with a builder number.

Instead of `/js/app.js` you should point to `/js/123/app.js` 123 being the build number.

On each deploy, increment the build number.

Then you need to do some rewriting, in order for the server to find `app.js` when there's a fake folder in the path.

Of course, static files are not reloaded until someone closes the browser and visits the page again or press F5).

To solve this, you can use AJAX to request `app.js` and see if it has been modified:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:'/js/123/app.js',
    cache:true,
    ifModified:true,                  
    success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
        console.debug(data);     // Returns undefined when response is 304 Not Modified
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

PHP:

```
ob_start(function($data) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "(/(?:js|css|img)/.*?\.(?:js|css|png|jpg|gif))",
        function($m) {
            if( file_exists(substr($m[0],1))) return $m[0]."/t=".filemtime(substr($m[0],1));
            else return $m[0];
        },
        str_replace(array_keys($rep),array_values($rep),$data)
    );
});
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/t=[0-9]+$ /$1
```

This automatically appends a specific timestamp to all images, styles and scripts: its modification time. Then, the `.htaccess` strips it off again.

This means that whenever one of these files are updated, cached versions are effectively invalidated immediately. Tested to work perfectly in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing your static content fold with a build number is a great way to do it.  To make sure that they always pull the latest after a build you need to combine that technique with a server side tag that renders html with the location of the static content taking the build number into account.  Of course if you are doing a 100% angular paradigm there is no such thing as a server side tag, so you need to violate the purity of your solution and have a jsp page or something similar that the user lands on after login (your welcome page) that then references your static content.  You can then end your server side code there and live in the pure static layout world from that point on if you like.